# Removing ?fbclid query string from the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/* index\.php?slug=$1
```

The main idea is to capture links and send them to a dispatcher which, if certain RegEx rules apply, calls a php file. Everything is sent to index.php, which does the RegEx comparison. *@CBroe, I try to match a URL pattern, and then select the correct php to call, according to an array of 'rules'=>'scripts'. See below.*

*Added: @iainn, it's an ages old system inspired in WordPress' "pretty URLs". I can't simply rewrite it all at the moment, I'm not allowed to allocate office time for that.*

E.g.:

```
$nodes = array(
    '/posts\/(?P<slug>.+)(\/*)$/'=>'posts.php',
    '/home(\/*)$/'=>'home.php',
)
```

It's been alright until Facebook started adding the ?fcbid querystring at the end of the URLs. *Added: @CBroe, now it just fails matching rules, because they don't expect a querystring.*

*Added: as @Adam S. suggested, some examples that work:*

```
http://something.com/posts/1589285645-title-of-a-post
http://something.com/posts/1589285645-title-of-a-post/
http://something.com/home
http://something.com/home/
```

And the following don't work

```
http://something.com/posts/1589285645-title-of-a-post?fbclid=whatever
http://something.com/posts/1589285645-title-of-a-post/?fbclid=whatever
http://something.com/home?fbclid=whatever
http://something.com/home/?fbclid=whatever
```

I've already tried several posts here with suggestions on dealing with this, but none of these apply to my setup.

How should I reformat my .htaccess file to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you only want to rewrite requests with a blank query string?

Comment: Just remove that `RewriteCond`?

Comment: Can you paste example of your urls which qualified for the htaccess rule and the facebook one?

Comment: _“It's been alright until Facebook started adding the ?fcbid querystring at the end of the URLs.”_ - and then? What _happened_? This is missing the actual _problem description_ so far.

Comment: _“which does the RegEx comparison”_ - comparison of _what_, exactly?

Comment: Though @anubhava answer works, I added details to my question as suggested by the people above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You're a life saver. I copied and pasted the rule you proposed, and worked like a charm without a single modification. Thank you very much for your time.